# How to validate phone number and email using jquery.validate.min.js?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have managed to adapt a jquery form validation example to work with my site, but I don't know how to make sure it's just numbers entered in the phone number field and just email addresses entered in the email field.

Please can anyone help?

Also wondering if there is anything that could be improved?

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.10.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(function() {
   $( "#quickform" ).validate({
           rules: {
                   name: {
                       required: true
                   },
                   phone: {
                       required: true,
                       phonevalidation: true
                   },
                   email: {
                       required: true,
                       emailvalidation: true
                   },
                   enquiry: {
                       required: true
                   }

           },
           messages: {
                   name: {
                       required: "Please enter your name."                         
                   },
                   phone: {
                       required: "Please enter your phone number."                         
                   },
                   email: {
                       required: "Please enter your email address."                         
                   },
                   enquiry: {
                       required: "Please enter your enquiry."                         
                   }
           },
   });
   $.validator.addMethod("phonevalidation",
           function(value, element) {
                   return /^[A-Za-z\d=#$%@_ -]+$/.test(value);
           },
   "Please enter a valid phone number."
   );
   $.validator.addMethod("emailvalidation",
           function(value, element) {
                   return /^[A-Za-z\d=#$%@_ -]+$/.test(value);
           },
   "Please enter a valid email address."
   );
});
</script>
```

EDIT:

There are already validation methods in the example but it is to not accept special characters. I just need to understand how to change the /^[A-Za-z\d=#$%@_ -]+$/ to email and number validation.

Comment: "I don't know how to make sure it's just numbers entered in the phone number field" — Don't. Instead, let people format their phone numbers. You can strip formatting characters out on the server.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. Sorry I should have been clearer. There are already validation methods in the example but it is to not accept special characters. I just need to understand how to change the /^[A-Za-z\d=#$%@_ -]+$/ to email and number validation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are already `email` and `phone` rules present in the validation framework

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.10.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.1/additional-methods.js"></script>
<script>
$(function() {
    $( "#quickform" ).validate({
        rules: {
            name: {
                required: true
            },
            phone: {
                required: true,
                phoneUK: true //or look at the additional-methods.js to see available phone validations
            },
            email: {
                required: true,
                email: true
            },
            enquiry: {
                required: true
            }

        },
        messages: {
            name: {
                required: "Please enter your name."                         
            },
            phone: {
                required: "Please enter your phone number."                         
            },
            email: {
                required: "Please enter your email address."                         
            },
            enquiry: {
                required: "Please enter your enquiry."                         
            }
        },
    });

});
</script>
```

Comment: @netrunner I've add a note along with it

Comment: That's great! I'm now using your example for the email address and the above answer for UK phone number validation. Thanks!

Comment: @ArunPJohny Your note just points to a js file to see available phone validations, which as far as I see still only covers US phone numbers.

Comment: @netrunner no, if you look inside the file there is a `phoneUK` rule

Comment: @Chris updated the answer to use `phoneUK` from the library, no need to write a custom rule

Comment: @ArunPJohny My bad, I was checking the wrong version of the file :)

Comment: After further testing Er.KT's UK phone number validation doesn't accept standard landlines for some reason. I tried phoneUK but it accepts anything :-/

Comment: Got it working. Just needed to include additional-methods.js :-)

Comment: @Chris I had added it in my answer

Comment: Lol ok phoneUK accepts 10 digit numbers. Not ideal but i guess it's the best I'm going to get without coding my own

Comment: Ye sorry Arun i just noticed that

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to construct a Regular Expression and match that to what the user enters and use the match() function.

For more info on how to construct the right regular expression (depending on your locale) go to [RegExp tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_obj_regexp.asp).

Comment: Thanks for the replies. Sorry I should have been clearer. There are already validation methods in the example but it is to not accept special characters. I just need to understand how to change the /^[A-Za-z\d=#$%@_ -]+$/ to email and number validation.

Answer (score 1):

I have UK phone number validation

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod('phoneUK', function(phone_number, element) {
                        phone_number = phone_number.replace(/\s+/g, '');
                        return this.optional(element) || phone_number.match(/^(\+44\s?7\d{3}|\(?07\d{3}\)?)\s?\d{3}\s?\d{3}$/);
                    }, 'Please specify a valid phone number');


                    $('#inputTelephone').rules('add', {
                        required: true,
                        phoneUK: true
                    });
```

Comment: That's perfect! I wasn't expecting to have it validate so it only accepted UK format phone numbers :-)

Comment: Actually after further testing it doesn't work properly. Wont accept my standard 0121 landline number with or without spaces :-/